# OnLoad function of page inside iframe is replacing single quotes with "&#39;" only when loaded by link inside frame, src change from parent works

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iframe

in my asp.net application (vb code behind) I have a page that has an iframe on the right side. The left side of the page (will refer to this as the parent page, the iframe will be the iframe) has a few tables, and when certain cells are clicked, it changes the src of the iframe using javascript to show a detailed account inside the iframe of the entry they clicked on. Inside the iframe at the top, there is a breadcrumb trail that shows the entries that must be followed in order to get to this entry (its sort of like a tree, there are different levels of entries and each one below is linked to a parent above, etc). These links are just simple html links that are created using a function on the VB side. My issue is that when I click on an entry from the parent page, everything loads correctly, but when I click on a link from with in the breadcrumb trail in the iframe - When scrolling my mouse over some images, I get an error with my javascript function that handles the mouseover. Both ways (changing the src or clicking a link in the frame) call the same page and function.  I believe I have found the issue - when clicking from the parent window - the javascript call for the mouse over looks like this.

```
onmouseover="imgOv(this, '../images/modify.gif')"
```

When clicking on the link in the iframe, the mouseover looks like this.

```
onmouseover="imgOv(this, &#39;../images/level_over.gif&#39;)"
```

Here is the code that generates this html. Can anyone see why my single quotes are turning into ' instead of just the quote like when the frames src is changed?

The code:

Here is navSpot - a placeholder in the details page. The info here is loaded from another VB library

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="NavSpot" Runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

on load of the details page (the details page is the page in the iframe, if clicked from the parent, the src of the frame is changed to the details page, if clicked from the link, it just uses an href to call the page). here is the code that handles the navSpot

```
    Dim myCtrl As UserControl = LoadControl("../include/NavDetailScreens.ascx")
    myCtrl.ID = "navControl"
    NavSpot.Controls.Add(myCtrl)
```

And here is the function that is called when NavDetailScreens.ascx is called - I am positive that the same exact parameters are being passed into the SP, and that there is no difference in changing the src or clicking the link already in the iframe (in regards to the parameters used for the stored procedure). The error section seems to come at the end, specifically the three lines towards the end of the sub, inside the if that starts with "If DS.Item("activity_enable") = 1 Then" - it seems like this is when the single quotes are turned into the & # 39; (used spaces so it didnt auto adjust to a single quote - no spaces in actual string that is in the JS function)

```
    Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Put user code to initialize the page here
    If Request.QueryString("standalone") <> "true" Then
        Dim strConn As String
        strConn = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("ConnectionString")
        Dim objConn As SqlConnection
        objConn = New SqlConnection(strConn)
        Dim myCmd As SqlCommand
        myCmd = New SqlCommand
        myCmd.Connection = objConn
        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        myCmd.CommandText = "SPNavigation"
        Dim lnChildCat As Integer
        Dim prmEntityID As New SqlParameter("@entityID", SqlDbType.BigInt)
        prmEntityID.Value = Request.QueryString("taskgrpid")
        Dim prmEntityCat As New SqlParameter("@entityCat", SqlDbType.Int)

        If Request.QueryString("taskgrpid") = "" Then
            prmEntityCat.Value = 35
            lnChildCat = 26
            prmEntityID.Value = DBNull.Value
        ElseIf Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory") = Request.QueryString("ptaskgrpcategory") Then
            If Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory") = 26 Then
                prmEntityCat.Value = 34
                lnChildCat = 34
            ElseIf Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory") = 10 Then
                prmEntityCat.Value = 11
                lnChildCat = 11
            ElseIf Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory") = 11 Then
                prmEntityCat.Value = 12
                lnChildCat = 12
            ElseIf Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory") = 12 Then
                prmEntityCat.Value = 13
                lnChildCat = 13
            ElseIf Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory") = 35 Then
                prmEntityCat.Value = 35
                lnChildCat = 26
            ElseIf Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory") = 34 Then
                prmEntityCat.Value = 10
                lnChildCat = 11
            End If
        Else
            If Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory") = 26 Then
                prmEntityCat.Value = 26
                lnChildCat = 34
            Else
                prmEntityCat.Value = Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory")
                lnChildCat = Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory")
            End If
        End If



        Dim prmIsMilestone As New SqlParameter("@isMilestone", SqlDbType.Int)
        If Request.QueryString("milestone") = "true" Then
            prmIsMilestone.Value = 1
        Else
            prmIsMilestone.Value = 0
        End If

        Dim prmResID As New SqlParameter("@resid", SqlDbType.Int)
        prmResID.Value = Session.Item("user_id")
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(prmEntityID)
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(prmEntityCat)
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(prmResID)
        myCmd.Parameters.Add(prmIsMilestone)
        Dim DS As SqlDataReader
        objConn.Open()
        DS = myCmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim objRow As TableRow
        objRow = New TableRow
        Dim objCell As TableCell
        Dim lc As LiteralControl
        Dim dynImg As Image
        While DS.Read
            objCell = New TableCell
            lc = New LiteralControl
            lc.Text = "<br>" & DS.Item("act_name")
            dynImg = New Image
            If Request.QueryString("mode") = "create" Then
                If IsDBNull(DS.Item("act_frm_params")) = False Then
                    If Request.QueryString("milestone") = "true" Then
                        If DS.Item("act_frm_params") = "&mode=create&milestone=true" And CInt(lnChildCat) = CInt(DS.Item("act_task_category")) Then
                            dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_edit")
                        Else
                            dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_disabled")
                        End If
                    Else
                        If DS.Item("act_frm_params") = "&mode=create" And CInt(lnChildCat) = CInt(DS.Item("act_task_category")) Then
                            dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_edit")
                        Else
                            dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_disabled")
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_disabled")
                End If
            ElseIf Request.QueryString("mode") = "edit" Then
                If IsDBNull(DS.Item("act_frm_params")) = False Then
                    If Request.QueryString("milestone") = "true" Then
                        If DS.Item("act_frm_params") = "&mode=edit&milestone=true" Then
                            dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_edit")
                        Else
                            dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_disabled")
                        End If
                    Else
                        If DS.Item("act_frm_params") = "&mode=edit" And CInt(Request.QueryString("taskgrpcategory")) = CInt(DS.Item("act_task_category")) Then
                            dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_edit")
                        Else
                            dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_disabled")
                        End If
                    End If
                Else
                    dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_disabled")
                End If
            Else
                If DS.Item("activity_enable") = 1 Then
                    dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name")
                    dynImg.Style.Add("cursor", "hand")
                    dynImg.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "imgOv(this, '" & DS.Item("act_img_name_over") & "')")
                    dynImg.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "imgOu(this, '" & DS.Item("act_img_name") & "')")
                    dynImg.Attributes.Add("onclick", "imgclick('" & DS.Item("act_frm_name") & "', '" & DS.Item("act_frm_params") & "" & "', " & DS.Item("act_task_category") & ")")
                Else
                    dynImg.ImageUrl = DS.Item("act_img_name_disabled")
                End If
            End If
            objCell.Controls.Add(dynImg)
            objCell.Controls.Add(lc)
            objCell.CssClass = "infotext2"
            objCell.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top
            objCell.Width = Unit.Pixel(50)
            objRow.Cells.Add(objCell)
        End While
        DS.Close()
        objConn.Close()
        tlbNav.Rows.Add(objRow)
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks again for your help.

Edit: when changing the single quotes to regular quotes, they are being replaced with & quote instead of & # 39 - so this was not a solution.

Edit 2: seems like this is cause of .net 4.0 and a security update - and rolling back to 3.5 would fix this issue, but this is not an option. any other solutions to stop this conversion?

Comment: found a little bit on the issue here - http://forums.asp.net/p/1554455/3818604.aspx - going to try to make a javascript function on the parent to change the src to see if we can get around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to solve this issue by instead of clicking on the links with an href, changed them to call a javascript function in the parent page, which changes the src of the iframe instead, and the comma's are not being converted this way.